# Warning: public/pickup is not a socket or a fifo

Tags: linux, postfix-mta

I installed postfix and sendmail on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago), I am trying to send mail as follows:

```
[root@mcscs-pr-labc01 etc]# echo "Hello world" | sendmail ns906g@att.com
postdrop: warning: public/pickup is not a socket or a fifo
```

But no mail is getting send.

If I use 'mail' instead of 'sendmail' I get following:

```
[root@mcscs-pr-labc01 etc]# echo "Hello world" | mail ns906g@att.com
[root@mcscs-pr-labc01 etc]# postdrop: warning: public/pickup is not a socket or a fifo
```

It gets stuck here. The message is a warning message and not an error message, still the mail doesn't get sent.

Any idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Examine the output of

```
   ls -l /var/spool/postfix/public/pickup
```

On my machine:

```
   # ls -l /var/spool/postfix/public/pickup
   prw--w--w- 1 postfix postdrop 0 Nov 22 17:44 /var/spool/postfix/public/pickup
```

Also check if the "pickup" line in /etc/postfix/master.cf looks like this:

```
pickup    fifo  n   -   -   60  1   pickup
```